# Drag and Drop in Windows 7 not working in admin mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

**Problem**

I have a strange problem. I have written an application in MFC(using VS2003) to handle "Drag and Drop" of file/folder. When I run the application in administrator mode, DnD is simply rejected but works in other way (when I don't choose to run in admin mode).

**Work around**

I have tried several ways :

http://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-enable-drag-and-drop-for-an-elevated-mfc-application-on-vistawindows-7/

http://www.cdartdisplay.com/forum/showpost.php?p=12302&postcount=13

[http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?499909-MFC-Drag-and-Drop-works-on-XP-broken-on-Vista-Windows-7-(](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?499909-MFC-Drag-and-Drop-works-on-XP-broken-on-Vista-Windows-7-%28)

None of them worked for me.

**Development tool details**

IDE : Visual Studio 2003 version 7.1.3088
OS : Windows 7 Professional (64 bit)

Please suggest me a solution to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is by design, UIPI does this.  You cannot drag from a non-elevated app into an elevated one.  No workaround.

Comment: You are wrong Hans, it is very much possible. How Explorer would notify TaskBar registration message to elevated windows, if it crashes and comes back again? I have done it using the code mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Explorer and Windows does many tricks around. Enable all messages:

```
ChangeWindowMessageFilter (WM_DROPFILES, MSGFLT_ADD);
ChangeWindowMessageFilter (WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ADD);
ChangeWindowMessageFilter (0x0049, MSGFLT_ADD);
```

Got it from:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/2fa935cf-be57-4bcc-9b96-7ee5a6b2b7a5/

Comment: D+D stopped using Windows messages a long time ago.